# NMF Matrix Multiplication not reducing error

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

In NMF we have to iteratively multiply matrix `W` and `H` such that it begins to approximate `V`.

```
# specify the rank
r = 4
print('r:', r)
# Generate some synthetic data to create V0 from Wtrue and Htrue.
# Our challenge is then to find V ~ V0 by iterative learning, 
# starting from random values of w and H.
Wtrue = np.array([[1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8]])
Htrue = np.array([[9,11,13],
                 [10,12,14]])
# Wtrue = np.random.rand(40,5) # nxr, i: 1 -> n, a: 1 -> r
# Htrue = np.random.rand(5,10) # rxm, i: 1-> r, mu: 1 -> m
V0 = Wtrue @ Htrue # converge: v ~ wH
print('V0:\n', V0)

# Dimensions of data (n rows and m cols)
n, m = V0.shape
print('n(row), m(col):', V0.shape)

# Normalise columnwise
V = np.zeros(shape=(n,m))
for i in range(m):
    V[:,i] = V0[:,i] / np.max(V0[:,i])
print('V:\n', V)
    
# Initialise W as n rows and r cols
W = np.random.rand(n,r)
# Initialise H as r rows and m cols
H = np.random.rand(r,m)
print('wH:\n', W@H)
print('W:\n', W)
print('H:\n', H)

# Maximum iteration of 40k
maxIter = 8
f = np.zeros(shape=(maxIter, 1))

# Initial error
f[0] = np.linalg.norm(V - W @ H, ord='fro')
print('Initial error: ', np.log(np.linalg.norm(V - W @ H, ord='fro')))
print('Learning weights...')
for iter in range(maxIter-1):
    # Update W
    for i in range(n):
        for a in range(r):
            S = V[i,:] / (W@H)[i,:] @ H[a,:]
            W[i,a] = W[i,a] * S
    # Update H
    for a in range(r):
        for u in range(m):
            T = V[:,u] / (W@H)[:,u] @ W[:,a]
            H[a,u] = H[a,u] * T
    
    # Measure Error
    f[iter+1] = np.linalg.norm(V - W @ H, ord='fro')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
ax.set_title('Convergence of NMF')
ax.set_xlabel('Iteration')
ax.set_ylabel('log(Error)')
ax.plot(np.arange(maxIter), np.log(f), c='m')
ax.grid(True)
print('Final error: ', np.log(np.linalg.norm(V - W @ H, ord='fro')))
plt.savefig('images/NMF_convergence_r32.png')
```

The problem is that my solution stops reducing the error value after a small number of iteration. The correct code should reduce the error value with higher number of iteration.

This is where the problem most likely lies:

```
    # Update W
    for i in range(n):
        for a in range(r):
            S = V[i,:] / (W@H)[i,:] @ H[a,:]
            W[i,a] = W[i,a] * S
    # Update H
    for a in range(r):
        for u in range(m):
            T = V[:,u] / (W@H)[:,u] @ W[:,a]
            H[a,u] = H[a,u] * T
```

Here's the plot I'm getting: [image: NMF Convergence]

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I am not sure but could be because of operator precedence issue with `@` matmul operator here. Check this https://bugs.python.org/issue33390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a quick fix after reading chapter 10 of [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) by Toby Segaran.

First make sure you run `from numpy import *` then inside the main loop:

```
# ...
for iter in range(maxIter-1):
    # Update W
    wn=(V@transpose(H))
    wd=(W@H@transpose(H))
    W=matrix(array(W)*array(wn)/array(wd))
    
    # Update H
    hn=(transpose(W)*V)
    hd=(transpose(W)*W*H)
    H=matrix(array(H)*array(hn)/array(hd))
    
    # Measure Error
    # ...
```

This has given me the correct plot:

[image: Correct NMF convergence]